# How to add extra attributes to users collection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using `Accounts.createUser` to add new users to the database, but the problem is that, not all the attributes are added.

Here is my code to add new user:

```
import {Accounts} from 'meteor/accounts-base';

Template.addingUser.events({
    'submit #addUser': function (e, t) {

        e.preventDefault();

        Session.set('name', t.find('#name').value);
        Session.set('email', t.find('#email').value);
        Session.set('telephoneOffice', t.find('#telephoneOffice').value);
        Session.set('telephoneHouse', t.find('#telephoneHouse').value);
        Session.set('salary', t.find('#salary').value);

        let userId = Accounts.createUser({
            username: Session.get('name'),
            password: "123456",
            email: Session.get('email'),
            telephoneOffice: Session.get('telephoneOffice'),
            telephoneHouse: Session.get('telephoneHouse'),
            employeeSalary: Session.get('salary'),
            annualLeave: 14

        }, function (err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log('It worked...');
        });

        Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId);


    }
});
```

only the name, email, and password are added.

How do I include the other information as well such as `telephoneOffice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the extra data inside the `profile` object.

```
Accounts.createUser({
  username: Session.get('name'),
  password: "123456",
  email: Session.get('email'),
  profile: {
    telephoneOffice: Session.get('telephoneOffice'),
    telephoneHouse: Session.get('telephoneHouse'),
    employeeSalary: Session.get('salary'),
    annualLeave: 14
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`Accounts.createUser` does not accept custom arguments beyond username, email, password, and profile. The default functionality for passing custom user info is to pass those fields such as `telephoneOffice` as part of the `profile` object, which is copied to `user.profile` in the document inserted to the user collection.

For example:

```
let userId = Accounts.createUser({
        username: Session.get('name'),
        password: "123456",
        email: Session.get('email'),
        profile: {
          telephoneOffice: Session.get('telephoneOffice'),
          telephoneHouse: Session.get('telephoneHouse'),
          employeeSalary: Session.get('salary'),
          annualLeave: 14
        }
    });
```

Note that the `user.profile` fields are [by default modifiable by users](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile). So it's there by legacy, but Meteor actually recommends avoiding using it for storage.

If you want those fields to be on `user` instead of `user.profile`, What you can do is to pass your custom params on the `profile` object as above, and then override the default behavior using [Accounts.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser). Something like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile)
    _.extend(user, options.profile);
  return user;
});
```

See more info here: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#custom-user-data